# remove/restore Dropdown Menu at specific window size with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to remove the drop down menu when my window-size is less than 710px. The problem is, when I go from small (<710) to big (>710) the drow down menu doesnt appear again..

First I tried: else{} but some how it saves the `.hover` function. After this I have tried the code you can see here. Now it doesnt save the variable "UlLiUl" for the if-statement (The console says: undefined).

In this link you will see the site where I'm trying this: [link to site](http://ergosr.bplaced.net/Praxis.html).
Can you help me please? I'm still new to `jQuery`.

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    DropDownMenu();

    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        DropDownMenu();
    });
    function DropDownMenu() {

        if ($(window).width() > 710) {
            $('nav ul li').prepend(UlLiUl);
            $('nav ul li').stop().hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500);
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
                }
            );
        } else {
            var UlLiUl;
            UlLiUl = $('nav ul li ul').detach();
        }
    }
});
```

### EDIT

Its way better now than before, but still not exactly what I want. My sub ul's have all a different content, but with your jquery code it shows always the same sub ul. In this [jsfiddle.net/17fpnoc5/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/17fpnoc5/1/) at the html part you can see which specific sub ul belongs to which specific li of the nav (There are just 2 sub ul at the moment). With "first-child" it shows me the sub ul only at "Startseite" but in html for "Startseite" there is no sub ul. Thank you!!

Comment: it's because you are calling UlLiUl and it's defined inside the else part. So, let you defined it before if else statement then use it whenever you want

Comment: I tried this before as well. e.g. in this way before the if-statement: "var $nav_ul_li_ul = $('nav ul li ul');" and "$('nav ul li').prepend($nav_ul_li_ul);". But my internet launcher got freezed then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it something like this one. I'm sure that this time you'll be satisfied with my answr.

This is new fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/61dfhz95/7/

And her is the code:

```
    $(document).ready (function () {
        UlLiUlValue=[];
        $('nav ul li ul').each(function(index, value){
            UlLiUlValue[index]='<ul>'+$(this).html()+'</ul>';
            $(this).parent('li').attr('class', 'has_sub');
        });
        DropDownMenu();
        $(window).bind('resize', function () {
            DropDownMenu();
        });
        function DropDownMenu() {
            $('nav ul li ul').detach();
            if ($(window).width() > 710) {
                $('nav ul li.has_sub').each(function(index,value){
                    $(this).append(UlLiUlValue[index]);
                });
                $('nav ul li').stop().hover(
                    function () {
                        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500);
                    },
                    function () {
                        $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
                    }
                );
            } else {
                $('nav ul li ul').detach();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much and have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

It'll help you. You was calling UlLiUl inside the if statemetnt but it's defined inside the else statement. Here I took it before if else statement. I stored the all html element of sub ul. then checking the window size if is greadter then html element is being prepend else it's any html element then remove it.

====================

## Edit

http://jsfiddle.net/61dfhz95/1/

Check this one.
As per my understanding you want to hide sub ul of li
but there was no ul inside the li. So let you have some ul inside the li. on resizing if window width will be less then ul content will be erased, and if width will be more ul content which is stored inside a variable will be placed inside the li.
Right now it's placing inside the every li. Now use it according to your need such as

inside the if part use: `$('nav ul li:first-child').prepend(UlLiUl);` or any id, class, etc. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/61dfhz95/3/

```
    $(document).ready (function () {
        var UlLiUl;
        UlLiUl = '<ul>'+$('nav ul li ul').html()+'</ul>';//.detach();            
        DropDownMenu();

    $(window).bind('resize', function () {
        DropDownMenu();
    });
    function DropDownMenu() {

        $('nav ul li ul').detach();
        if ($(window).width() > 710) {
            $('nav ul li').prepend(UlLiUl);
            $('nav ul li').stop().hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(500);
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(500);
                }
            );
        } else {
            $('nav ul li ul').detach();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It still doesnt want to work. This is what happens: http://ergosr.bplaced.net/Praxis.html

Comment: It's not too difficult, but it'll take time to answer. Because I'm in office right now. Whenever I'll be free from office, you'll get the answer

Comment: nice to hear :), Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Passenger please see my second answer, it's according your desire. Don't forget to accept it.